# Compare column value to an int in dataframe with python

Tags: python, dataframe, comparison

I have a dataframe dframe and i want to iterate over lines of my column number if number <5 then my column STATE takes the value 'vv'
if number is between [5..17] so my value of my column STATE takes 'xx'.
ELSE STATE takes 'yy'.
SO I wrote this code but it doesn't work..

ANy helps please.

thank you
`

```
for it in dframe['number']:
        if (it < 5):
            dframe['STATE'] = 'vv'
        elif (it >= 5 & it < 17):
            dframe['STATE'] = 'xx' 
        else: 
            dframe['STATE'] = 'yy'`
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more information, what exactly is going wrong? Expected output vs actual output. Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in one line with a list comprehension:

```
dframe['STATE'] = ['vv' if (i < 5) else 'xx' if (i >= 5) & (i < 17) else 'yy' for i in dframe['number']]
```

Comment: it works perfectly.. Thank You But my method i don't know what it don't work in python

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider upvoting and accepting. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work for you.

```
dframe['state']=''
dframe.loc[dframe['number'] <5, 'state'] = 'vv'
dframe.loc[(dframe['number'] >5) & (dframe['number']<17), 'state'] = 'xx'
dframe.loc[dframe['state'] =='', 'state'] = 'yy'
```

Comment: my STATE IS always empty with this code .. Thank youu

Comment: @flayyem Hi, I improved the answer and it should work. please check and confirm.